# Select mysql between last 1 hour

Tags: mysql

I wonder if someone could help me. I was trying to select records from my table that falls within the past hour from this table. But for reason it keeps returning all the records.

```
finished
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 11:00:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 12:55:00
2019-05-17 13:00:00
2019-05-17 13:00:00
2019-05-17 13:00:00
2019-05-17 13:25:00
2019-05-17 13:25:00
2019-05-17 13:25:00
2019-05-17 13:25:00
2019-05-17 13:25:00
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE finished > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

I ran the query at 12pm and was expecting only records between 11-12pm. And if I run it again later - let's say 3pm, I expect records for between 2-3pm.
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table can have future events, you have to specify the upper bound as well.

```
SELECT *
       FROM people
       WHERE finished >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
             AND finished < now();
```

Comment: Fantastic, this seems to be what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, you are saying at `12` that show me all the data which has timestamp bigger than `11`

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

will result in

```
2019-05-17 11:00:00
```

at

```
2019-05-17 12:00:00
```

so your Query looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE finished > 2019-05-17 11:00:00
```

so your record with timestamp `2019-05-17 12:55:00` will satisfy above condition and will show up in result.

in order to achive what you want you have to add upper bound in your query

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE finished > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and finished <= NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `BETWEEN` is another option. Make sure to run `SELECT NOW()` to make sure you don't need to fix the time zone or something.

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE finished BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3600 SECOND) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE finished > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

"**NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR**" will return the time stamp of 1 hour from now.
So, "**finished >NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR**" will compare timestamp in your database with the time 1 hour before from now.

Comment: It's the exact same query. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE finished > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);`

Outputs: 

`select id
     , finished
  from people
  where finished > (now() - interval 1 hour);`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it